My project cannot register more than one user on firebase
I developed a login signup page for my project and successfully registered one user. Later I tried registering more than one user and got this error message "Registration failed. The Supplied auth credential is incorrect, malformed or has expired." Below is my activity and build gradle project and build gradle module.
            public class RegisterActvity extends AppCompatActivity {
            EditText email, phoneNumber, userName, password;
            Button btnRegister;
            TextView textLogin;
            FirebaseAuth mAuth;
            FirebaseDatabase database;
            DatabaseReference reference;
            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_register_actvity);

            btnRegister = findViewById(R.id.button);
            email = findViewById(R.id.inputEmail);
            phoneNumber = findViewById(R.id.inputPhone);
            password = findViewById(R.id.inputPassword);
            textLogin = findViewById(R.id.account);
            userName = findViewById(R.id.userName);
            mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
            textLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActvity.this, LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            }
            });
            btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
            reference = database.getReference("users");
            String inputEmail = email.getText().toString();
            String pass = password.getText().toString();
            String inputPhone = phoneNumber.getText().toString();
            String User = userName.getText().toString();

            if (inputEmail.isEmpty()) {
                email.setError("Email can not be empty");
            }
            if (User.isEmpty()) {
                userName.setError("User can not be empty");
            }
            if (pass.isEmpty()) {
                password.setError("Min password length should 6 characters");
            }
            if (inputPhone.isEmpty()) {
                phoneNumber.setError("linenumber can not be empty");
            } else {
            mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(inputEmail, pass).addOnCompleteListener(new 
            OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            Toast.makeText(RegisterActvity.this, "User registered Successfully", 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            startActivity(new Intent(RegisterActvity.this, LoginActivity.class));
            } else {
            Toast.makeText(RegisterActvity.this, "Registration Failed" + 
            task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            }
            });
            HelperClass helperClass = new HelperClass(phoneNumber, email, userName, 
            password);
            reference.child("users").child(inputPhone).child("userName").setValue(User);
            reference.child("users").child(inputPhone).child("email").setValue(inputEmail); 
            reference.child("users").child(inputPhone).child("phoneNumber").
            setValue(inputPhone);
            reference.child("users").child(inputPhone).child("password").setValue(pass);
            }
            }
            });
            }
            }

            buildscript {
            dependencies {
            classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3"
            classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
            }
            }// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all 
            sub-projects/modules.
            plugins {
            id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.2' apply false
            id 'com.android.library' version '7.2.2' apply false
            }
            task clean(type: Delete) {
            delete rootProject.buildDir
            }                               

            plugins {
            id 'com.android.application'
            id("com.google.gms.google-services")
            }
            android {
            compileSdk 33
            defaultConfig {
            applicationId 'com.example.greendiner'
            minSdk 23
            targetSdk 33
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
            }
            buildTypes {
            release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard- 
            rules.pro'
            }    }
            compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            }
            buildFeatures {
            viewBinding true
            }
            }

            dependencies {
            implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
            implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
            implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.4.0'
            implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
            implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
            testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
            implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
            androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
            androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
            implementation "androidx.biometric:biometric:1.1.0"
            implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:18.0.0'
            implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.6.0'
            implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.2.1'
            implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.2.1'
            implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display-ktx:20.3.2'
            implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database-ktx:20.2.2'
            implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:22.3.1'
            // OneSignalSDK
            implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[4.0.0, 4.99.99]'
            //gif
            implementation 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.19'
            }

